# How to calculate time complexity of this recursion?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm interested in calculating the following code's time and space complexity but seem to be struggling a lot. I know that the deepest the recursion could reach is n so the space should be O(n). I have no idea however how to calculate the time complexity... I don't know how to write the formula when it comes to recursions similar to this forms like: `f(f(n-1))` .
if it was something like, `return f3(n-1) + f3(n-1)` then i know it should be O(2^n) since T(n) = 2T(n-1) correct?

Here's the code:

```
int f3(int n)
{
     if(n <= 2) 
         return 1;
     f3(1 + f3(n-2));
     return n - 1;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Recursive call result is not used.

Comment: If you are not sure, but have a guess of the complexity you can always try to support your guess by timing the runtime for different values of `n`. This is also a good approach to get a first idea what the complexity might be.

Comment: The nested version is not different from the version you are comfortable with. You can rewrite it to your liking, e.g. x = f3(n-2); then y = f3(1 + x).

Comment: can you elaborate further @AnthonyLabarre? I don't seem to understand quite well how to calculate after rewriting.. don't i have to account for the return values from the nested calls?
@MrSmith42 I'm not that good at guessing but if i were to guess i would've guessed O(2^n) which is incorrect.. this question is from an exam and they only have final answers. the final answer is O(2^(n/2))... if i were to try for different values of n i might get close to the wrong guess..

Comment: I believe the O() has something to do with the exit case being `n <= 2`. if you switch out 2 for 1, you get roughly 2x the amount of calls. if the exit case was 3, you get roughly 1/2 as many function calls. so the base is O(2^n), and then it is forced into a general O(2^(n/x)) where x is dependent on the return case. it's been a while since I have done O analysis but this is the only thing I see forcing it to not be 2^n

Comment: I think the O() is with n/2 because of the call that is f3(n-2) rather than the case being n<=2. the thing I don't know how to do is how to write the formula for nested calls like f(f(n-x)) or something. Thank you for your comment @rhavelka

Comment: @BukLau maybe. `1)` I guess my main thought was that you are creating a binary tree with the recursion. for every x > 0, you have essentially one less horizontal layer to your tree. every layer you don't compute. `2)` I also just realized I read it wrong. I thought it was `return n`, not `n - 1`

Comment: @rhavelka the last return isn't reached. it reaches the base case`return 1;` and then goes back. when it's called with n-2, the total calls are n/2. if it was n-3 it would be n/3, however i still don't know how to put it in a mathematical formula to calculate the runtime.. i only know it's with n/2 because i could see the final answer. i would've never been able to guess and be sure without calculating.
I've tried drawing the tree but i'm struggling a lot with it, it doesn't look like a tree so i'm definitely doing something wrong :(. thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `f3(n) = n - 1` for all n, so the line `f3(1 + f3(n-2))`, first `f3(n-2)` is computed, which returns `n - 3` and then `f3(1 + n - 3)` = `f3(n-2)` is computed again!
So, `f3(n)` computes `f3(n-2)` twice, alongside with some `O(1)` overhead.
We got the recursion formula `T(n) = 2T(n-2) + c` for some constant `c`, and `T(n)` is the running time of `f3(n)`.
Solving the recursion, we get `T(n) = O(2^(n/2))`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But how did you figure out that `f3(n) = n-1` for all n? The last line in the code is never executed due to the return in the base case. How does it not vary after each return call?

Comment: When `n <= 2` is reached, we can say `T(n)` is constant, thus just add this case to our `c`.

Comment: To be more exact, when n is even the lowest n we will get to will be 2, so `f3(n)=n-1` holds for all n. when n is odd, when we get to `n=3` it will compute `f3(1)` which returns 1 and hence then `f3(2)`. they both take the same time so we don't need to seperate it to cases.